# Creating a multiple select filtering system for related MySql database tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my database.

Table 1 = wp_bibliography, stores information about journal articles

```
+------------+---------+
|  post_id   |  title  |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | Nature  |
| 2          | Science |
| 3          | Neuron  |
+------------+---------+
```

Table 2 = wp_term_relationships, stores different tag terms

```
+------------+---------+
|  object_id |  tag_id |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | 106     |
| 2          | 108     |
| 3          | 106     |
+------------+---------+
```

The post_id and object_id are related.

I would like to create a multi select check box so that I can return results for either 108 or 106 or both. For example if I check 106 and 108 I will have post_ids 1,2,3 returned, if I just select 106 I have post_ids 1 & 3 returned and if I select 108 I just have post_id 2 returned

```
<div class="list-group-item checkbox">
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="106" >106</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="108" >108</label>
</div>
```

The query which runs on submission (and does work) is as follows but needs to be made dynamic (which I can do), the example below is if the user has selected both 106 & 108.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_bibliography x 
JOIN wp_term_relationships y 
ON y.object_id = x.post_id 
WHERE y.term_taxonomy_id IN(106,108) 
GROUP BY post_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

My question is this the best way of doing what I desire? Note my multi-select checkboxes above will have as many as 20 values such, that

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 20
```

Is there are more efficient, better way of doing this?

Comment: Yep, that works for me.

Comment: Yes, that work As long you can handle the dynamic part you can pass the 20 check box to the `IN ()`, But dont use `SELECT *` You will get a random `tag_id`  value as result. And I will use `COUNT(tag_id)` to make clear what are you counting.  Also seem like you cant have duplicate tags, if that were the case you need add `COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id)`

Comment: Thank you Juan Carlos...

Comment: *"SELECT * You will get a random tag_id value as result."* @JuanCarlosOropeza MySQL 5.7.5+ fully supports ISO/ANSI SQL:1999  standard optional feature which is called [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) it's menitoned in the [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) manual... His query can in fact be valid but we need to know the table structures to know that for sure..

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are right. if every post has only one tag will be OK. But OP mention `wp_term_relationships, stores different tag terms` So my guess was an article can have multiple tags